# AutoHotKey script with if-else simultaneously active for GetKeyState on NumLock

Tags: autohotkey

I have written an AHK script to swap <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> and other similar keys so that I don't have to press shift when writing HTML and CSS, but I'd like to be able to toggle this using the NumLock button. My script's code is as follows:

```
if (GetKeyState("NumLock","T"))
{
    $[::Send {Raw}{
    $]::Send {Raw}}
    $+[::Send `[
    $+]::Send `]
}
else
{
    $,::Send `<
    $+,::Send `,
    $.::Send `>
    $+.::Send `.
}
```

In practice, whilst this script is running both the <kbd>[</kbd>/<kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd>/<kbd><</kbd> keys are "reversed" regardless of whether the NumLock is toggled on or off.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, that's a good question and you were very close! I believe what you were looking for is [context-sensitive hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm). Please see if the following works for you:

```
#if (GetKeyState("NumLock","T"))
    $[::Send {Raw}{
    $]::Send {Raw}}
    $+[::Send `[
    $+]::Send `]
#if !(GetKeyState("NumLock","T"))
    $,::Send `<
    $+,::Send `,
    $.::Send `>
    $+.::Send `.
#if
```

Note that it isn't always necessary to conclude a context-sensitive section with `#if`, but I like to do it as it is easier for me to keep track of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. So AHK makes a difference between `if` and `#if`. Who could have imagined that

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I managed to solve it with this code

```
#InstallKeybdHook
#SingleInstance force
#MenuMaskKey vkE8
#if GetKeyState("NumLock" ,"T") and WinActive("Window")
 a::
 MsgBox certo
 return

#If
```